# Can I create a library project using SpringBoot?

Tags: spring-boot

Can I create a library project using SpringBoot?

Import jars from a Java project that does not uses SpringBoot.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation : [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot)

> Spring Boot makes it easy to create stand-alone, production-grade Spring based Applications that you can "just run".

IMHO, If you want to create a library, you can create with regular spring project.

Comment: I built the jar using spring boot. I have included a jar via "Add Library" in another project, but I can not use classes in that jar. Could you please give me some documentation that I can refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can. You can create another framework on top of spring boot and use that as a dependency just like how you use spring boot in your project

Comment: I built the jar using spring boot. I have included a jar via "Add Library" in another project, but I can not use classes in that jar. Could you please give me some documentation that I can refer to?